# Prevent default construction of array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

```
element* elements = new element[size.x];
```

This will build X elements with the default constructor. During my program, I would like to construct each element with different constructor parameters, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < size.x; ++i) 
    elements[i]  = element(i);
```

Is there any way to prevent and needless default instanciation (that I don't want to implement) and a needless calle to `Operator=` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `std::vector<element>`, which will do this for you (using `push_back` or `emplace_back`)?

Comment: No reason, it's just out of curiosity. BTW I don't understand why I could do this with emplace_back on vectors but not the equivalent on arrays

Comment: Well `std::vector<>` can do it, so it's obviously possible... ;-]

Comment: Why not just use malloc?

Comment: @ds1848 : Because this is C++ -- losing type safety isn't something to strive for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it doesn't hurt your design you can use a double pointer to achieve this

```
element ** elements = new element * [size.x];

for(int i=0; i < size.x; ++i) 
    elements[i]  = new element(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is really a problem for you, don't use an array.  Use a `std::vector` with the default constructor.

> explicit vector ( const Allocator& = Allocator() );
>   Default constructor: constructs an empty vector, with no content and a size of zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can *copy*-initialize automatic arrays, which will usually be optimized out to straight in-place construction, with a brace initializer:

```
elements e[] = { elements(1,2,3), elements(), elements('a', true) };
```

That does not work for dynamic arrays, though. In C++11 you can specify an initializer list, but that too is copy-initialization, not direct initialization:

```
elements * e = new elements[2] { elements(1,2,3), elements('a', true) };
```